# Java consumer group missing?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I recently set up a test Kafka cluster. I am running a consumer group listening on items and things seem to work. The name of consumer group is `default`. What surprises me is that listing consumer groups gives me an empty list:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
$
```

Also, explicitly querying the offsets doesn't yield anything:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group default
No topic available for consumer group provided
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
```

**Do I need to manually create a consumer group using `kafka-consumer-groups.sh —new-consumer` to be able to track its offsets?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I am using the new consumer/producer API. This means I need to use the `—new-consumer` flag. Example:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
default
$
```

Comment: Which version of kafka you are using? I am using kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1, but I don't find any shell script or bat script in the bin directory with the name of kafka-consumer-groups.

Comment: neither one is working with 0.10.0.0, no idea how to list/delete consumer groups

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you. I suggest you ask a new question or look in Kafka documentation.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that answer!  I had the exact same problem.  This option was in my face, but totally non-intuitive.